# Kendo ListView populating with undefined data

Tags: json, kendo-ui

My KendoListView populates the correct number of items but does not populate the fields correctly. The data is being passed in from my controller as a JSON result and I am getting the correctly number of items in my list view but the template renders "Member: undefined undefined". The strange thing is that this is almost a one-to-one copy and paste from a similar view I have and it works fine.

ListView code:

```
@section head
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataSource;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            MemberID: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                            FirstName: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                            LastName: { editable: false, nullable: false }
                        }
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetMembers", "Pages", new { area = "Admin" })",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#memberList").kendoListView({
                autoBind: false,
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    if (dataSource.total() == 0) {
                        $("#MemberList").html('<tr><td>There are no members at this time.</td></tr>');
                    };
                },
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#memberTemplate").html())
            });

            dataSource.read();
        });
    </script>
}

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="memberTemplate">
<tr>
    <td style="padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px">
        Member: #= FirstName # #= LastName #
    </td>
</tr>
</script>

<div>
    <table>
        <tbody id="memberList"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The model schema that is passed in:

```
string Address1
string Address2
string Address3
bool BeLeader
string City
string EmailAddress
string FirstName
string LastName
Guid MemberID
string PhoneNumber
bool ReceiveEmails
Guid StateID
string Zip
```

Update: My Controller method is returning the correctly number of arrays but they are blank...not sure why. Here's my constroller code:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMembers([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<Member> results = new List<Member>();

    try
    {
        results = adminServices.GetMembers();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    JsonResult test = Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Did you check what is you server returning...? Try opening in your browser the url, it should look like: `{ "Total" : 2, "Data" : [ { "FirstName" : "fn1", "LastName" : "ln1", "MemberID" : 1},  { "FirstName" : "fn2", "LastName" : "ln2", "MemberID" : 2} ] }`

Comment: You're correct. My data is empty. I'm getting {"Data":[{},{}],"Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null} which I don't understand since I can see my data in the JSON result just before the return (updated code above).

Comment: At least now you know that you have to search for in the server and not in the client :-) And you also know that the number of elements is correct but they are empty.